# Git not excluding even untracked files

Tags: git, gitignore

I am running into a problem with git. I have initialized a new git repo and wrote ".gitignore" first but git is not excluding those files and folders. I have tried "git rm -r --cached" and then added only .gitignore file but it all went in vain.
[[image: screenshot of IDE]]

Tried unstaging the files but as you can see in the screenshot, `git status` is still showing the **.venv** and **pycache** folder that should be excluded in the **untracked section**.

Comment: Have you saved `.gitignore` after editing it?

Comment: @ElpieKay yes i have saved it... and after saving i have also ran "git add .gitignore" but not working

Comment: Does it work if you remove all lines except `.venv` in `.gitignore`?

Comment: Have you tried `.venv/` ?

Comment: @ElpieKay no, first i only wrote .venv but it did not work so then i tried copying from internet and that copied one also did not work

Comment: @Basil yes, first i had written ".venv/" and as it did not worked i thought to use wildcard but there was a problem too...

Comment: Open `git-bash`, run `file /d/Work/python_script/.gitignore` and see what it prints.

Comment: Does `__pycache__/` work?

Comment: Does your gitignore file use LF or CRLF line endings? Have you verified with [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)?

Comment: @ElpieKay it says

$ file /d/work/python_script/.gitignore
/d/work/python_script/.gitignore: Unicode text, UTF-16, little-endian text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: @Basil nope, same issue as .venv

Comment: @knittl its CRLF and running git check-ignore .venv outputs nothing, it looks like its not even reading .gitignore :/

Comment: Save the file as UTF-8. UTF-16 will not work.

Comment: @j6t Thank you for this!!! UTF-8 worked. such a small thing yet caused trouble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [@j6t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6868543/j6t) , **UTF-16** encoding for **.gitignore** will not work. So, save it as **UTF-8** and the problem will be gone. If you run into the same problem then before following any other procedures make sure correct encoding has been selected while saving the file.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer. Such a subtle issue should be more well-known.

Answer (score 1):

Git ignore lists can have `!<pattern>` lines that undo or add an exception to an ignore pattern that was previously set.

For example:

```bash
# mydir/.gitignore
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```

Git loads its ignore list from (highest precedence to lowest):

1. Patterns specified on the command line.
2. Whatever `core.excludesFile` is set to, by default `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore` aka `~/.config/git/ignore`
3. `.git/info/exclude`
4. `<current directory>/.gitignore`

I would check:

1. Is there a `.venv/.gitignore` file that contains some exclusion lines?
2. Is there an exclusion line later on in the root-level `.gitignore` file that mentions `!.venv` or `!/.venv`?

Comment: the .venv doesn't have any. I dont find any global ignore rules. Also, as a temporary fix i am indeed using .git/info/exclude but i would like to realize where is the problem so that it won't  bother me in future.